# Why is Azure CI DACPAC trying to drop a column that doesn't exist and failing?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

I'm trying to deploy DB updates to SQL Server via Azure CI DACPAC, but I keep getting a data loss might occur error causing the deployment to fail.

> Warning SQL72015: The column [dbo].[MyTable].[NonExistantField] is being dropped, data loss could occur.

Why would it try to drop a column that doesn't exist? There's no reference to this field that I can find anywhere. How do I get it to stop trying to drop the column?

Secondly, and more generally, is there a setting somewhere where I can force it to deploy even if data loss occurs? I don't care about data loss, it's irrelevant and this error forces me to update the entire database by hand.

Comment: Sorry, the error message clearly says that there is not only a field, but also data in  the table. This is not a DACPAC errior, it s a SSMS safety feature. Check your options. Now, why does it drop? Because DACPAC brings the database INTO THE DEFINED STATUS. Which seems not to have the field - but it is in the database, hence a drop.

Comment: @TomTom The error message is wrong. I'm looking at the target DB. The field does not exist. It has never existed.

Comment: Are you sure you look at the correct database? That would be - interesting. Gave up on DACPAC a long time ago for issues related to - well - the order of things, so - not a specialist in the current iteration.

Comment: @TomTom Quite sure. There is only one DB present on the target server so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Even if you didn't care about data loss, the deploy would still not go through because dropping the non-existent column would fail, causing the rest of the deployment to be aborted -- so the first order of business remains identifying where it's coming from. This is true especially because, if the deployment doesn't agree with you on the DB structure, there's no telling what other havoc it could wreak if you just told it to ignore and proceed.

Comment: Yes there's a tickbox that allows data loss. But you really need to work out the issue. I suggest you do a schema compare between the project and the database, and let it tell you what it thinks is different. You can also manually generate the drift script and insepct it

Comment: I don't use DACPAC, but I have seen something similar in SSMS designer generated table change scripts: Could it be that you are changing data types / adding constrains to existing columns that require a column to be re-created and SQL Server does this by creating a copy and then dropping original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the exact problem was, but the solution was to go into the DB via SSMS, drop the offending table and then allow it to be recreated via deployment.

Oddly, in my first attempt I dropped the table and recreated it in SSMS and then did the deployment and it still failed with a warning about data loss.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are trying to deploy your updates. It will be useful to see your deployment step to get some recommendations. As an example, if you deploy through [SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15), you can use `/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss='False'` option.